# c# convert string array to 2 dimensional char array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

I need to convert a string array into a 2 dimensional char array

Example: My string array looks like

```
string[] months = {"January", "February", "March"....};
```

I want to convert it into a `char[,]` something like this (not sure about syntax)

```
char[][] = {
    {'J','a','n','u','a','r','y'},
    {'F','e','b','r','u','a','r','y'},
    {'M','a','r','c','h'}
};
```

what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: A `char[,]` is a *rectangular* array, meaning each dimension has the same length. That is not the case in your example. You could convert it to a `char[][]`

Comment: what kind of 2D array does your DLL expect? `[,]` or `[][]` ? in the first case you probably would need to fill the missing items with empty strings

Comment: Yes.. my bad.. Dll expects 2D array of form [][].. I will edit the question..

Comment: @ChaitanyaArawakar - Does my answer answer your question? or do you need help to turn it into a `char[,]`?

Comment: @GiladGreen you answer was very helpful.. it solved my issue.. thanks for your help..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string[] months = { "January", "February", "March" };
char[][] result = months.Select(item => item.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Gilad green I need to pass 2d char array as a parameter to one of the functions from DLL, so this option will not work for me.. but thanks for your effort to help..

Comment: @ChaitanyaArawakar this will gives you 2d array of char, what you looking for. Use `char[][] result =` instead of `var`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
string[] months = {"January", "February", "March"};

char[][] jaggedOfChar =new char[3][];

for (int i = 0; i < months.Length; i++)
{
    char[] s = months[i].ToCharArray();
    jaggedOfChar[i] = s;
}
```